# How to reference a dynamic multiple range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a chart using a source data list (two separate columns) which can vary in column height depending on user inputs.
I am storing my dynamic value in a variable called "chartRange".
I originally made the sub using a fixed range, using a single code line, which works perfectly. 
I replaced this single code line:

```
Set chartRange = ActiveSheet.Range("E8:E69,G8:G69")
```

with these 3 new lines of code:

```
Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E8":"E" & chartRange)
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G8":"G" & chartRange)
Set myMultipleRange = Union(r1, r2)
```

I am trying to make these 3 new lines of code work, but getting error message.
Can someone help me correct the code problem?
I have included the full sub below.
Thanks in advance.

```
Dim chartRange As Integer
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim totalPymts As Integer
Dim r1, r2, myMultipleRange As Range


' this variable is used to define table size
totalPymts = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5, 4).Value


  'my data range for the chart using single line
  ' Set chartRange = ActiveSheet.Range("E8:E69,G8:G69")

  ' the 3 new lines that dont work
  Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E8":"E" & chartRange)
  Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G8":"G" & chartRange)
  Set myMultipleRange = Union(r1, r2)

'Create a chart
  Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.add( _
    Left:=Range("a1").Left, _
    Width:=450, _
    Top:=Range("a5").Top, _
    Height:=260)

'Give chart some data
  cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=myMultipleRange

'Determine the chart type
  cht.Chart.ChartType = xlLine


'Ensure chart has a title
  cht.Chart.HasTitle = True

'Change chart's title
  cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Repayments Schedual"

  'Remove X-axis

  ' remove legend entry 1
    Worksheets("sheet1").ChartObjects(1).Chart _
 .Legend.LegendEntries(1).Delete


End Sub
```

Comment: Set the chart series themselves up to reference dynamic named ranges. Is it just two series?

Comment: i dont see you setting the value of `chartRange` anywhere. your code results in `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E8:E0")`. you probably meant to use `totalPymts`

Comment: A part from the comments above, your declaration of: `Dim r1, r2, myMultipleRange As Range` means that only 'myMultipleRange` is set as a range. `r1` and `r2` as set as variants. Although in this case that might not be the problem (on the other hand it might be), if you want to declare all of them as `Range`, change it to: **`Dim r1 as Range, r2 As Range, myMultipleRange As Range`**

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go.

Comment: yes just two series.

Comment: Yes your right I did a name swap, however fixing this still results in error somewhere in the 3 new code lines.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your FAST answers. Looks like I had a few careless errors in my code. All the feedback helped me finally get this sub working.